# How to check if a group exists in cognito user pool and then create if it doesn't?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Goal is to add given user to given group-name, but if the group doesn't exist then i need to create the group and then add the user to that group.

```js
 cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(groupParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.message === "Group not found.") {

                        var params = {
                            GroupName: userType,
                            UserPoolId: userPoolId,
                            Precedence: 5,
                            // RoleArn: 'STRING_VALUE'
                        };
                        cognitoidentityserviceprovider.createGroup(params, function(err, data) {
                            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                            else {
                                    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(groupParams, function(err, data){
                                       if(err) {
                                           console.log(err, err.stack);
                                       } 
                                       else {
                                           console.log(data);
                                       }
                                    });
                            }
                                // successful response
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(err, err.stack);
                    }

                } // an error occurred
                else console.log(data); // successful response
            });
```

This code works but i am afraid of that fine day when AWS will decide to change the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could make use of the `ListGroups` API call?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListGroups.html

List all the groups in the pool, looking for the one you are trying to add the user to. If it exists, just add the user. If it doesn't exist, create it first and then add the user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using error.mesaage "Group not Found", I went for error.code "ResourceNotFoundException" as it is more reliable and less likely to be changed by AWS.